# How to store token in android?

Tags: android, retrofit, interceptor

I am new to android development, I am developing simple mobile application where I am calling the login service by making use of Retrofit. Once I get the response(token) from login service how should I store and make use of that token in OkHttp interceptors.

Thanks in advance.

APIClient

```
package com.example.dell01.firstapplication.service;

import com.example.dell01.firstapplication.UserSession;

import java.io.IOException;

import okhttp3.Interceptor;
import okhttp3.OkHttpClient;
import okhttp3.Request;
import okhttp3.Response;
import retrofit2.Retrofit;
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory;    


public class APIClient {

    public static final String BASE_URL = "actual url";
    public static Retrofit retrofit = null;

    OkHttpClient okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient().newBuilder().addInterceptor(new Interceptor() {
        @Override
        public Response intercept(Chain chain) throws IOException {
            Request originalRequest = chain.request();
            Request.Builder builder = originalRequest.newBuilder().header("Token", "token here");
            Request newRequest = builder.build();
            return chain.proceed(newRequest);
        }
    }).build();


    public static Retrofit getAPIClient(){
        if(retrofit == null){
            retrofit = new Retrofit
                    .Builder()
                    .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create()).build();

        }

        return retrofit;
    }
}
```

APIInterface

```
package com.example.dell01.firstapplication.service;

import com.example.dell01.firstapplication.model.Token;

import retrofit2.Call;
import retrofit2.http.Field;
import retrofit2.http.FormUrlEncoded;
import retrofit2.http.POST;   


public interface APIInterface {

    @POST("user/authenticate")
    @FormUrlEncoded
    Call<Token> getToken(@Field("username") String username, @Field("password") String password);
}
```

Comment: you can use shared preferences if it is just light weight data or SQLite Databases

Answer (score 2):

You can use **SharedPreferences**

Here is the complete documentation : 
[SharedPreferences](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/SharedPreferences.html)

Example :

Save:

```
 SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("myPrefs", MODE_PRIVATE);
 preferences.edit().putString("token", hawkerauthToken).commit();
```

Retrieve:

```
   String token = preferences.getString("token","");
```

Comment: This is a good way to handle. Just could add the posibility of encrypt the token

Comment: Thank you. I've tried this approach but unable get the string in APIClient Class. Could you please send me code snippet to refer

Comment: SharedPreferences preferences = getSharedPreferences("MYPREF", MODE_PRIVATE);

                        SharedPreferences.Editor editor = preferences.edit();

                        editor.putString("token", res_token.getToken().toString());
This is what I've tried

Answer (score 0):

You should Store them in  shared preferences.
shared preferences by default private in addition to you can encrypt this token before store it in shared preferences .

Comment: @ArashHatami I think  concept is the most important and the code will be so easy